# Pass dynamic parameters to factory / composition root in Ninject (or perhaps any container)

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject, ioc-container

Here is an example.

```
foreach (var doc in documents)
{
    var processor = this.factory.Create();
    processor.Process(doc);
}
```

The `factory` internally calls `kernel.Get<IDocumentProcessor>()`.

I'd like all the document processor's dependencies' lifetimes to be "scoped" to this composition root. This configuration seems to do what I want:

```
kernel.Bind<IEntityContext>().To<EntityContext>().InCallScope();
```

Now each object graph rooted at the document processor has a unique, shared entity context for accessing the database. But this

1. affects all entity contexts everywhere in the application (which may be ok, but seems hard to discover), and
2. only seems to work for bindings known about statically.

I think my question is, how can I achieve the same scoping / lifetime management effect with "contextual" or dynamic information? Perhaps I want to have the document instance itself injected into all children of the new root:

```
    var processor = this.factory.Create(doc)
    processor.Process()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get what's your problem. But the first example with passing the doc along the method call should be the prefered way normally.

Comment: Hi Remo, thank you for all the work you are doing on Ninject at the moment! What I mean is: In the second case, I'd like any and all dependencies of the document processor to be able to receive the correct *IDocument*. Does that make sense?

Comment: From what I know from your post it feels wrong to treat doc as a dependency. It is more like an input value for the processor and therefore the first option seems to fit better. But difficult to give you an answer without knowing the whole problem.

Comment: Ok, how about this: is there a way to say *just* that each new IDocumentProcessor (and its dependencies) should get a new, shared IEntityContext - instead of changing the lifetime scoping for all IEntityContexts everywhere in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ninject 3.0.0 you can do

```
kerne.Get<IProcessor>(new ConstructorArgument("doc", doc, true));
```

But to me there still seems to be a design flaw to have doc as a dependency of the processor. It would be better to create the processor once and reuse it for multiple documents by passing the document to the Process method. I still do not get what's the issue with this due to the fact that the question does not show the actual problem.

Comment: Sorry Remo, I'll see if I can improve the question. I agree that injecting the document looks wrong, but I'm trying to create an injection "context" for processing a document. The nub of the question is "I'd like all the document processor's dependencies' lifetimes to be "scoped" to this composition root". I assume the ConstructorArgument will only be injected into the processor, not into its dependencies? Pete

Comment: By specifying that the ConstructorArgument shal be inherited it is passed to the children.